# Symbols don't change colour when changing Eclipse color theme

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the Eclipse Color Theme plugin.
When I change the theme all the colours change except for `()[].={}`.etc.
They stay black, and as I'm trying to use a dark theme that makes things difficult.

Anyone had the same issue, or know a way around it?

EDIT:

The problem was that the syntax colouring wasn't being set properly when using Groovy.
[This solved it](http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/changing-syntax-highlighting-for.html)

Comment: You should answer your own question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that the syntax colouring wasn't being set properly when using Groovy.
[This solved it](http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/changing-syntax-highlighting-for.html)

> Window->Preferences->Groovy->Editor. In this settings page you will find the rest of the settings you need to change. Set the operator, bracket colors to something more visible (and any other fine tweaks you may wish)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the colors for operators/brackets (which are by default in black) by going to:
Preferences -> Groovy -> Editor
Here you can manually set the colors.